# Is there a cache memory in android smartphone as there is in laptop/desktop?

Tags: cache

I know there are l1/l2/l3 cache in laptops but is the same kind of cache memory available in android smartphones. Also here in this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) when website writes about lrucache what does that mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache) for different definitions of cache.

Speaking of [cache memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_memory): yes there is, in a similar way to desktop processors. Take [Qualcomm Snapdragon 820](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=processor&id=613&c=qualcomm_snapdragon_820_msm8996) as an example:

> L1 Instruction Cache per Core:    32 Kbyte I-Cache
>
> L1 Data Cache per Core:   32 Kbyte D-Cache
>
> Total L2 Cache:   1536 Kbyte L2

As for the "lrucache" you talked about, it's merely a part of memory space allocated to store content (in that context, bitmaps). It's much more similar to the other caches e.g. Web Cache on the page, in that it's purely software based - no dedicated software, dynamically allocated and released on storage. Different concept.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a cache, but depending on your phone, I can't tell you exactly where yours are. In the Samsung Galaxy Series (they're similar across the line), you go into your app manager. The recent download makes it really difficult to clear your caches, but, you go into each app, wait for it to come up, click on the storage option, and at the bottom of each app, you will see "clear cache". Do not clear your data, unless you're uninstalling the app. Hope this helps!

Comment: -1: different concept of "cache" here.